# canon ip1180 printer driver for ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I'm running ubuntu, and I can't get the Canon IP1180 printer to print. Do you know what to do?
Thanks.

Comment: I wish I could help you. The closest I can test was the Canon ip1100 which works. Can you provide more information. For example, when you connect the printer to Ubuntu, go to the terminal and type dmesg. Then paste here the last 5 to 10 lines it says. This way we know what Ubuntu sees when you connect the Printer.

Answer (score 1):

According to canon, the IP1800 uses the same drive.  Some printer models can share the same driver.  Canon says online that PIXMA ip1180 and canon PIXMA ip1800 use the same generic driver.

That being said, you can download the driver from [canon](http://www.canon.co.uk/Support/Consumer_Products/products/printers/InkJet/PIXMA_iP_series/PIXMA_iP1800.aspx?DLtcmuri=tcm:14-742541&page=1&type=download).